How would one describe non-proportional relationships?
We usually describe linear proportional relationships (y=mx) as either direct or inverse.
But how would we describe the relationship in a linear non-proportional relationship (y=mx+b), or a non-linear non-proportional relationship that clearly has a consistent relationship (such as y=√x; as in, if x increases then y increases)?
Do we say “x is directly related to y” instead of “x is directly proportional to y”?
Also, is there a symbol to describe it (like ∝ in proportional relationships)?

"The relationship between $x$ and $y$ is related/governed/mediated by $y = f(x)$", where $f$ is some function so $f(x)$ is an explicit expression in $x$.
